# How to get data month wise sqflite in Flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqflite

[Image for how does data look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkl1I.png)  I am making an expense tracker app using flutter, I want to show the sum of expenses done by the user every month for example:

```
Month              Amount Spended
January              2000
February             1600

Database columns:
"CREATE TABLE $TABLE_EXPENSES ("
      "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
      "$COLUMN_NAME TEXT,"
      "$COLUMN_AMOUNT TEXT,"
      "$COLUMN_UNNECESSARYEXPENSES INTEGER,"
      "$COLUMN_CATEGORY TEXT,"
      "$COLUMN_DATETIME TEXT"
      ")",
```

I am using sqflite to create a database and I am storing data as text. I want to retrieve expenses of every day in a month and then sum up the expenses of every day and show it in ListTile

Edit:

Query: 'SELECT * SUM(COLUMN_AMOUNT) FROM TABLE_EXPENSES WHERE COLUMN_DATETIME >= ? AND COLUMN_DATETIME <= ?'

This is the error that I am getting (for query):

```
E/SQLiteLog(10318): (1) near "SELECT": syntax error
E/flutter (10318): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE SELECT * SUM(COLUMN_AMOUNT) FROM TABLE_EXPENSES WHERE COLUMN_DATETIME >= 2019 AND COLUMN_DATETIME <= 1989) sql 'SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE SELECT * SUM(COLUMN_AMOUNT) FROM TABLE_EXPENSES WHERE COLUMN_DATETIME >= ? AND COLUMN_DATETIME <= ?' args [2019, 1989]}
```

Function which I am currently using:

```
Future getDataJan() async{
final db = await database;
sumJan= db.rawQuery(
    'SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES WHERE DATETIME >= ? AND DATETIME <= ?',
    [2021-01-01, 2021-01-31] ).then(Sqflite.firstIntValue);
finalJan=sumJan.toString();
```

}

Image:
[errorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pR2e.png)

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Where is the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the question? Please include it to the question. Also make sure to read [How do I ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Post sample data of your table.

Comment: I've added it hanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can operate with a date with format like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS` and create requests to database for search entities between month.

Date format example:

```dart
DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS').format(date)
```

Query example:

```dart
return database.query(
  tableName,
  where: 'date >= ? and date <= ?',
  whereArgs: [from, to],
)
.then((data) => data.map(_fromMap).toList());
```

Variables in example:

1. `from` - first day of month (2020-10-01);
2. `to` - last day of month (2020-10-31);
3. `?` in `where` - takes values from `whereArgs` (first `?` - `from`, second - `to`);

Note: in comments describes that you should use SQFLite tooling for creating requests and do not use raw queries (for performance reasons).

Select example

```dart
final result = await database.rawQuery(
  'select * sum(COLUMN_AMOUNT) from TABLE_EXPENSES where COLUMN_DATETIME >= ? and COLUMN_DATETIME <= ?',
  [from, to],
).then(Sqflite.firstIntValue);
```

Comment: can i use group by month over here and if yes hw can I use it?

Comment: You can try to use`groupBy`. Something like `group by date`,

Comment: Please don't *interpolate* into a where clause.  Use placeholders.  See bobby-tables.com for details.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Thanks, I am complete the answer.

Comment: I am using SQFlite only, thanks for your updated answer and reply I will try this one..

Comment: Future getDataJan() async{
    final db = await database;
    sumJan= db.query(TABLE_EXPENSES,
        where: 'SELECT SUM(COLUMN_AMOUNT) FROM TABLE_EXPENSES WHERE COLUMN_DATETIME >= ? AND COLUMN_DATETIME <= ?',
        whereArgs:[2021-01-01, 2021-01-31] );
  }  can I use it like this as I need sum as well?

Comment: yeah i am getting one ::[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE SELECT * SUM(COLUMN_AMOUNT) FROM TABLE_EXPENSES WHERE COLUMN_DATETIME >= 2019 AND COLUMN_DATETIME <= 1989) sql 'SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE SELECT * SUM(COLUMN_AMOUNT) FROM TABLE_EXPENSES WHERE COLUMN_DATETIME >= ? AND COLUMN_DATETIME <= ?' args [2019, 1989]}

Comment: Please verify your SQL syntax.

Comment: I don't know where am i wrong can you please help me??

Comment: SELECT SUM(COLUMN_AMOUNT) FROM TABLE_EXPENSES WHERE COLUMN_DATETIME >= ? AND COLUMN_DATETIME <= ?', whereArgs:[2021-01-01, 2021-01-31]      here it is

Comment: And you get error in SQL query or on the Flutter side?

Comment: I am getting error on sql query can you please help me?

Comment: Yes, can you add error message to the question?

Comment: I have added the query as well as the error I am getting

Comment: but i want to store the sum of that amount in a variable, how can I do that?

Comment: You can do this by call `count` function from sqflite and extract a value by `Sqflite.firstIntValue` method.

Comment: okay but then i would need to do the same for every month how would I differentiate it , I am not getting it please explain, currently I am making a function and then calling its variable :::::: 'Future getDataJan() async{
    final db = await database;
    sumJan= db.query(TABLE_EXPENSES,
        where: 'SELECT * SUM(COLUMN_AMOUNT) FROM TABLE_EXPENSES WHERE COLUMN_DATETIME >= ? AND COLUMN_DATETIME <= ?',
        whereArgs:[2021-01-01, 2021-01-31] );
    finalJan=sumJan.toString();
  }'

Comment: Can you add your function to the question?

Comment: I have added that

Comment: You need to call raw query from sqflite, without `where` statement.

Comment: can you please provide an example to me? It would be really helpful

Comment: I tried what you said but now I am getting an error the image for same has been posted in "errorImage"

Comment: You need to extract value with `await`. Database get result as `Future`.

Comment: but i am doing it, I have updated my function (in question) can you please check it and tell me ?

Comment: You need to call function by this way: `sumJan = await db.rawQuery`.

Comment: Delete this line `then(Sqflite.firstIntValue)` and add this `then((result) => result['sum('COLUMN_AMOUNT')'])`;

Comment: No it is showing an error when I type result, error "Undefined name 'result' ".

Comment: I guess the problem is in my function it is mentioned under "Function i am using" I am trying to get data in sumJan=query* then I am parsing it to string finalJan and then I am calling finalJan in my main file where I need to display the sum, I guess somewhere here I am doing wrong I guess the way of assigning in sumJan is wrong please refer to the question for the code of the same.

Comment: You can extract your database from the app's folder and test it with [SQLite Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Comment: Okay i will try that